# How to prevent airflow from backfilling dag runs?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, airflow

Say you have an airflow DAG that doesn't make sense to backfill, meaning that, after it's run once, running it subsequent times quickly would be completely pointless.

For example, if you're loading data from some source that is only updated hourly into your database, backfilling, which occurs in rapid succession, would just be importing the same data again and again.

This is especially annoying when you instantiate a new hourly task, and it runs `N` amount of times for each hour it missed, doing redundant work, before it starts running on the interval you specified.

The only solution I can think of is something that they specifically advised against in [FAQ of the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html)

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially `datetime.now()` as it can be quite confusing.

Is there any way to disable backfilling for a DAG, or should I do the above?

Comment: I am struggling with this behaviour, Airflow always kicks subsequent DAG run immediately after manual run. I already have catchup=False, looks like airflow always triggers scheduled run for current interval which I do not want, I want it to execute only future interval. Anyone has any idea ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Upgrade to airflow version 1.8 and use catchup_by_default=False in the airflow.cfg or apply catchup=False to each of your dags.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#catchup_by_default

Comment: Thanks. This is way better than the LatestOnlyOperator.

Comment: I have set catchup_by_default=False, yet Airflow still backfills the jobs. Any idea why? I'm running version 1.8

Comment: @OllieGlass Are you sure you applied it to the correct container, I don't know exactly what your setup is, but that definitely matters. You can also try applying it to specific DAGs if you're unsure.

Comment: @OllieGlass - did you figure it out?  I am getting the same non-behavior.

Comment: @sage88 - what do you mean by "correct container"?  The airflow doc isn't exactly explicit on where to place the setting.

Comment: @Nick I actually wasn't able to get the default setting working either so I ended up just putting `catchup=False` on all my DAGs like `DAG('example', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 5 * * *', catchup=False)`

Comment: @AR7 - thanks for the tip - I'll give it a try.  I had erroneously put "catchup" in the default args...  maybe that *should* work, but it didn't for me.

Comment: @Nick the default args object consists of arguments applied to the **tasks** running under the DAG **not to the DAG** itself. I was also initially confused by this.

Comment: also not seeing the `catch_by_default=False` working and I run airflow edge (i.e. master)

Comment: `catchup_by_default=False` in `default_args` also had no effect for me; however setting `backfill=False` on the DAG worked ....

Comment: I'm going to have to doublecheck if we're using `backfill=False` because we had to resort to renaming the DAG on 1.8 when `catchup_by_default=False` didn't work.

Comment: The question should be how to prevent airflow from catch/backfilling a task on a dag where catchup=True. It is obvious how to set catchup=False now. Maybe in the old version of airflow this was not the case but the question no longer makes sense otherwise.

Comment: I have catchup_by_default=False in both airflow.cfg and default args as well as catchup=False for the dag.  They don't work at all.  As soon as I unpause a new dag, it gets back filled right away.

Comment: @Sam Please see m0meni's comment above. The argument must be applied to the DAG, not the the tasks. As such it should not be included in the default args, it should be applied as a DAG argument.

Comment: @sage88 Yep I read through all the comments to make sure. I set catchup=False for the Dag and have catchup_by_default=False in the airflow.cfg. But unpausing a Dag backfills right away in the UI.

Comment: I'm using Airflow v1.10.0 and am still seeing this issue

Comment: Same here, on Airflow 1.10.1. I am setting ```catchup=False``` on all dags, and I still get backfill.

Comment: I'm using Airflow 1.10.2 and setting backfill=False (applied to the DAG). Backfill still occurred.

Comment: I'm using airflow 1.10.5. I am setting catchup=False, but Dag backfills again. Is this issue solved?

Answer (score 20):

Setting catchup=False in your dag declaration will provide this exact functionality.

I don't have the "reputation" to comment, but I wanted to say that catchup=False was designed (by me) for this exact purpose. In addition, I can verify that in 1.10.1 it is working when set explicitly in the instantiation. However I do not see it working when placed in the default args. I've been away from Airflow for 18 months though, so it will be a bit before I can take a look at why the default args isn't working for catchup.

```
dag = DAG('example_dag',
        max_active_runs=3,
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5),
        default_args=default_args)
```

Comment: I'm running `airflow 1.10.14` and this does not work, at least not when using the DebugExecutor

Comment: Running airflow 1.10.12 and its still not working.

Comment: Just saw that by default `catchup_by_default` is a `String` set to True instead of `Boolean`. Not sure if thats an issue ! 
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/configurations-ref.html#catchup-by-default
Can we have this default to False as so many people dont need/have issues turning it off.

Answer (score 15):

This appears to be an unsolved Airflow problem.  I know I would really like to have exactly the same feature.  Here is as far as I've gotten; it may be useful to others.

The are UI features (at least in 1.7.1.3) which can help with this problem.  If you go to the Tree view and click on a specific task (square boxes), a dialog button will come up with a 'mark success' button.  Clicking 'past', then clicking 'mark success' will label all the instances of that task in DAG as successful and they will not be run.  The top level DAG (circles on top) can also be labeled as successful in a similar fashion, but there doesn't appear to be way to label multiple DAG instances.

I haven't looked into it deeply enough yet, but it may be possible to use the 'trigger_dag' subcommand to mark states of DAGs. see here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/644/commits/4d30d4d79f1a18b071b585500474248e5f46d67d

A CLI feature to mark DAGs is in the works:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-commits/201606.mbox/%3CJIRA.12973462.1464369259000.37918.1465189859133@Atlassian.JIRA%3E
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/1590

UPDATE (9/28/2016):
A new operator 'LatestOnlyOperator' has been added (https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/1752) which will only run the latest version of downstream tasks.  Sounds very useful and hopefully it will make it into the releases soon

UPDATE 2: As of airflow 1.8, the `LatestOnlyOperator` has been released.

Comment: Update looks really promising! Thanks for keeping up with the question.

Comment: Note that LatestOnlyOperator sets the downstream tasks to a 'skipped' state.  Per the docs, the skipped states propagate such that where all directly upstream tasks are also skipped.  This makes the approach unsuitable when you'd (ew) like the upstream jobs to run successfully with out-of-date data.  In that case the best solution is to add an early operator in your code that escapes to success if the task is being run particularly late.

Comment: The backfill command for the cli looks like it's now available and is probably the best way to do this for now. https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/cli.html 
airflow backfill -h [hostname here] -m=True -s [startdate] -e $(date +"%Y-%m-%dT:%H:%M:%S")

Comment: I have tried the backfill mark success script trick, and it doesn't actually work to stop all running tasks/prevent backfilling (at least in 1.8). Hopefully it will work in future versions. Doing it manually through the UI works, but that's really only feasible if you're dealing with small numbers of backfilling tasks.